# Understanding difference between Custom Handler and SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-function

I'm new to Spring Cloud Function and came across it as one of best solution for developing FaaS based solution. I am specifically writing application for AWS Lambda Service which is back-end of API Gateway. I ran into very interesting problem with My test application and it is around Handler. My test application works well with Custom Handler written as -

```
public class UserProfileHandler extends SpringBootRequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {
}
```

which works well when configured as Handler in the AWS Lambda. Then I came across `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler` which is available in Spring Cloud Function dependency, so I wanted to get rid of `UserProfileHandler` hence I changed Handler configuration in AWS Lambda to `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler` instead of `...UserProfileHandler` and now lambda fails with following error message. Has anyone run into this problem?

```
{
  "errorMessage": "java.util.Optional cannot be cast to com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassCastException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.transformco.hs.css.userprofile.function.UserProfileFunction.apply(UserProfileFunction.java:16)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeFunction(BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.java:499)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.lambda$doApply$1(BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.java:543)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust$WeakScalarSubscription.request(FluxJust.java:99)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.BlockingIterable$SubscriberIterator.onSubscribe(BlockingIterable.java:218)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:70)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:53)",
    "reactor.core.publisher.BlockingIterable.iterator(BlockingIterable.java:80)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler.result(SpringBootRequestHandler.java:59)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootRequestHandler.java:52)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler.java:140)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler.java:43)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ganesh, I believe you have already raise the issue in Github of SCF. So as I stated there, we have recently did several enhancements, polished the sample and modified documentation by adding a [Getting Started guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/aws.html).

That said, with new generic request handler you no longer need to provide implementation of AWS request handler including `SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler`.

Simply write your boot application to contain function bean

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FunctionConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FunctionConfiguration.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
        return value -> value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

. . . and specify `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker` as a handler in AWS dashboard. We'll do the rest for you.

Comment: Upgrading to 3.0.1, solved an issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How can we test the function locally? Do we have to rely on including spring boot web?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. It's a function, you can just invoke its `apply` method in your unit test.